# undefined reference to `aireRectangle' and use of modularity in visual studio code using mingw

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw

I am making this post because it's been hours I am searching a solution for my program to work but I don't succeed finding an answer...
I'm beginning in learning C and for what I understand my file aire.c is not used correctly in my program. here are my codes:

exo1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "aire.h"

int main()
{  
    double resultat;
    resultat = aireRectangle(10.0,20.0);
    printf("%f est l'aire du rectangle", resultat);
    return 0;
}
```

aire.c:

```
#include "aire.h"

double aireRectangle(double longueur, double hauteur)
{
    return longueur * hauteur;
}
```

aire.h:

```
#ifndef aire_h
#define aire_h

#include <stdio.h>

double aireRectangle(double largeur, double hauteur);

#endif
```

Error log:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\berne\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOhDZEU.o:exo1.c:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `aireRectangle'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've found online that maybe my file aire.c wasn't considered as part of the project i'm using on Visual Studio code, but I've check and here is how the files are in my folder:

[image]

I know there's already topic about this but I really don't understand what the problem is. Is this about the settings of my Visual Studio code ? Like something I didn't checked?

Comment: What is your compilation command? You must tell the compiler to include all files that provide the required functions.

Comment: I'm just doing the right click and run code on my exo1.c ( ctrl+alt+N)

Comment: You need to compile aire.c as well.  Does your program generate a makefile where you can see actually what files are being compiled?

Comment: I don't think so, in my folder I only have the files of the screenshot and I've never heard of makefile before...

Comment: And I also don't know where to see what files are being compiled...

Comment: Have you looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497648/compiling-c-c-in-vs-code)?

Comment: I am checking this but does it mean I need to download the Cmake extension on visual studio code ? Because I don't have it at the moment

Comment: use a build tool: `Make`, `CMake`, ...

Comment: I have built a directory that looks just like the one you have, and executed the compilation command i sent, and it worked perfectly! This is the answer that I got when I executed the generated binary file: `200.000000 est l'aire du rectangle`

Comment: did you used it also on visual studio code ? I've added the extensions cmake and cmake tools to my visual studio code but didn't changed anything...

Comment: Yes using vsCode and MingW on a windows machine

Answer (score -1):

C is a compiled language so you absolutely have to compile it and execute the binary file!

Here try to copy and paste this into your terminal when you are in your project folder:

```
    gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 aire.c exo1.c -o main
```

Now to execute what you have written just write this into your console:

```
    ./main
```

However always writing this whole compilation command out is quite time consuming. So it is better to use a Makefile, which is a very handy way to compile your C code!

To make it simple to execute here is a simple Makefile!

```
all:
   gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 aire.c exo1.c -o main
```

now all you have to do is add a new file in VsCode and name it Makefile and paste this inside, now every time you will want to compile just write `make` into the terminal this will automatically execute the compilation command!

Comment: I was just editing my comment to explain how this is quite useless, but allows the user to learn the Makefile, the gcc and the gdb which are extremely helpful

Comment: actually it doesn't work saying : 
C:\Users\berne\OneDrive\Bureau\Labo>./main                                                                                                 '.' is not recognised as an internal or external command, an executable program or a command file.  (translated from French)

Comment: Can you show me if a new file has been created in your directory and the way you inputted the command into the terminal please

Comment: okay it worked when i type the cmd main, but is there a way to use this in my visual studio code ?

Comment: Yes you can type directly into the terminal that is present on the VsCode IDE, but please have a look at the edits I made, this will make it simpler

Comment: For Windows terminal, `./` might not be a proper prefix.